# Error with CRON executing PHP script

Tags: php, curl, cron, cpanel

I have a script called urlretrieve.php that I have placed on my web server. Lets say the web address is www.example.com/urlretrieve.php and when you visit this website, a file from another site is downloaded and placed into the same folder as urlretrieve.php on the web server. I need this website to be visited (executed) once a week. My question is, what should my cron job command be? At the moment I am using:

```
php /home/user/public_html/urlretrieve.php
```

and it isn't working. I have tested many others, but no luck.

I am using CPANEL.

This is the urlretrieve.php script

```
<?php 
$url = "ftp://alt.ncsbe.gov/data/ncvhis1.zip";
$fh = fopen(basename($url), "wb");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: The $PATH variable might not include the location of ``php``. Assuming it's running CentOS (with cPanel) try changing ``php`` to ``/usr/bin/php``. Also, the full cron entry in the crontab file should be ``@weekly /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/urlretrieve.php``, but if it's done through cPanel thats not needed.

Comment: Yes, I have the four set of numbers set up as every Friday at 4 at the moment, but have been changing them constantly for testing purposes.  I tried /usr/bin/php yesterday and no luck. This is what my server admin told me: "Your command looks good.  I think everything should run ok.  The call to just “php” should work without specifically locating the command in the bin or library connections."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this. Works.

```
33 14 * * 5 curl ftp://alt.ncsbe.gov/data/ncvhis1.zip > /home/user/ncvhis1.zip
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither work. Is it possible something is not set up correctly on the server?

Comment: sure, curl might not be installed, it might not be in the path, you might be using a different cron daemon.  Keep in mind that cron will run on Monday at midnight. not arbitrarily 1 time per week.  if you want some thing more abstract, you will need to read up on your cron servers documentation.

Comment: I set up the cron to run on Fridays at 2:20 with 
    20 14 * * 5 curl ftp://alt.ncsbe.gov/data/ncvhis1.zip > \ /home/user/ncvhis1_$(date "+%Y%m%d").zip

Comment: ok, make sure curl is in the path for the cron daemon, make sure your target directory exists. and you can remove that \[\n]  i only did that to avoid word wrap.

Comment: Yea, for some reason it isnt working for me. I'm having my web admin take a look at the errors on Monday to see if it's the servers fault. If this ends up working after he checks the settings I'll let you know.